# Create prototype with iPhone X round corner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, principle-app, dribbble

Hey guys (and to dribble experts),

I'm trying to create a prototype using iPhone X mockups. I'm following this [simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHpk1JS44yE&list=PLWlUJU11tp4deQOnSFNn_ekpS9GA5_7yP&index=14&t=0s) to do this (basically my flow : 1) create screens in Figma 2) export to principle to add animations 3) export animations in video foramt to photoshop 4) add the video to iphone X mockup 5) save as a gif

This works all fine but since screen on Iphone X has round corner + front camera area, the end result is not as expected

[image]

I didn't have to worry about this in Figma when designing screens since I dont't have to do this 'manually'

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add mask to your app image.

To do this you need to create new layer (mask) above iPhone mockup and make path of screen profile, fill it with solid color.

Then move layer with your app above mask and in Layers panel right-click on it and select Create clipping mask.

Below ugly fast example.

[image]